# How to center an oval border around text in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have this text and style:

```
<Text style={styles.problematicStyle}>{this.props.text}</Text>

problematicStyle: {
  borderRadius: 5,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'red',
}
```

it is wrapped in a view without any styling with other texts.

what this does does is

```
+--------------+    
|text          |
+--------------+
```

(stretches to the whole screen)

while I want

```
+----+
|text|
+----+
```

(I "drew" rectangular borders because it's easier but I need ovals)

I would prefer to not use static `height` and `width` but I can if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

Add following style properties:

```
problematicStyle: {
  borderRadius: 5,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'red',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
}
```

If you want some space between text and border add margin property to text style.

Comment: it looks like adding `justifyContent` and `alignItems` doesn't change anything really

Answer (score 1):

A background `View` with `problematicStyle` is needed to achieve this.

```
<View style={styles.problematicStyle}>
  <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
</View>
```